# Problem with speaker sound with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

After upgrading Carbon X1 gen 9 to Ubuntu 22.04 (from 20.04), there appeared strange problem with speaker sound in video conferences (Zoom, Preply) and also YouTube with Chrome.

The problem is as following: the speaker sound level is reduced when somebody speaks after a gap of silence, then the sound level is quickly increased to normal level. This creates the very strange fluctuating up/down sound level which when sound level is low at the start of each sentence. This problem was not there with Ubuntu 20.04 on the same laptop.

Thank you for your consideration.

Best regards,
Rustem